# Form buttons and social media icons stuck in vertical orientation

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im building my first website and am transferring CSS/HTML/JS code to wordpress. For some reason, the orientaion of my social media icons and form buttons(shown in code and screenshots below) will not orient horizontally. Can someone help me with this?

```
 <div id="form-wrap">
    <h4 id="contactme">Contact Me:</h4>
    <h5>Connect with me on social media:</h5>
    <div class="social">
    <a href="#"><img class="face" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Facebook.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="insta" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Instagram.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="link" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Linkedin.png" /></a></div>
<form>
<fieldset><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
<input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttons"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset Form" /></fieldset>
</form>
<h6>Site home page hand-coded by Curtis Vannor(under construction).</h6>
</div>



 .insta{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
.face{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

.link{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
.social{
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
form{
    width:70%;
    margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea{
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

[Picture of problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO6Ct.png)

Comment: try to set the `a` tag inside `social` with `display:inline-block` . they might have some styles from the theme you are using. in fiddle everything works ok https://jsfiddle.net/9mp2ttmr/

Comment: @Mihai T I just tried it and it still didn't work. I don't understand why this is happening because it looks perfectly fine in the live preview of my text editor. Also, the theme only had one stylesheet. Could it be automatically styling it somewhere else?